# Draco NGSIToCassandra processor giving error

Tags: cassandra, fiware

I am trying to persist data coming from Orion Context Broker to Cassandra by using ging/fiware-draco dockerhub image.

The moment I drag and drop the NGSIToCassandraError it throws an error as shown in the image. I tried the older versions of docker image with no help. Any suggestion  is appreciated.

[NGSIToCassandraError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9rE0.png)

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, this could well be an undocumented bug - I would suggest raising this as an issue over on the [Draco GitHub](https://github.com/ging/fiware-draco/issues), where you are more likely to get a reaction.

Comment: Hi. I see you in most of the fiware answer so i want to ask this. Is this NGSIToCassandraError processor used in production at all ? I tried all the ging/fiware docker image versions.Older versions like 1.3.1 or 1.3.4 does not throw this error, but they have their own bugs. None works as stable as NGSIToPostgreSQL.

Comment: @GorkhanErturk -  Although I answer where I can, there are over 30 context-data related open source projects to be found in the [FIWARE Catalogue](https://github.com/FIWARE/catalogue) -  no-one can know everything about each individual project in detail, that is why I suggest in this case you contact the development team directly on [GitHub](https://github.com/ging/fiware-draco/issues).  As currently written, your question is a poor fit for the Stack Overflow forum as it isn't strictly programming related.

Comment: @Jason Fox - Thank you. I raised the issue in github. Also thank you for all the support. I learned a lot throughout my fiware learning process. It is an awesome project. You guys are awesome.